# Show multiple columns values on labels with squarify.plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, squarify

I have a dataframe that I'd like to plot a tree map with `squarify`. I'd like to show the `country_name` and `counts` on the chart by editing the `labels` parameter but it seems only taking one value.

Example data

```
import squarify
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
d = {'country_name':['USA', 'UK', 'Germany'], 'counts':[100, 200, 300]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 4.5)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(dd.counts), vmax=max(dd.counts))
colors = [matplotlib.cm.Blues(norm(value)) for value in dd.counts]
squarify.plot(label=dd.country_name, sizes=dd.counts, alpha=.7, color=colors)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Expected output will have both `counts` and `country_name` on the chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a list of labels by looping simultaneously through both columns and composing  combined strings. For example:

```py
import squarify
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

d = {'country_name': ['USA', 'UK', 'Germany'], 'counts': [100, 200, 300]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
labels = [f'{country}\n{count}' for country, count in zip(dd.country_name, dd.counts)]
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 4.5)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(dd.counts), vmax=max(dd.counts))
colors = [matplotlib.cm.Blues(norm(value)) for value in dd.counts]
squarify.plot(label=labels, sizes=dd.counts, alpha=.7, color=colors)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: squarify plot with combined labels]